# SASS Overrides Inheritance

Tags: sass

I have a complex SASS and want to make some changes to the Inheritance. My challenge is how to handle the nesting:

Please see the code below

**This is the original SASS rule:**

```
.content-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  @media screen and ($desktops) {
    padding: 0;
  }
  @media screen and ($large-desktops) {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .grid-top-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    @media screen and ($desktops) {
      color: $color-white;
    }
    .grid-right {
      width: 100%;
      @media screen and ($desktops) {
        color: $color-white;
      }
    }

  }
  .grid-bottom-wrapper {
    color: $color-orange;
    @media screen and ($desktops) {
      color: $color-white;
    }
    .grid-right {
      width: 100%;
      @media screen and ($desktops) {
        width: 33.333%;
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

**I have an Inheritance here:**

```
.content-grid2 {
  @extend .content-grid;

}
```

**I like to make these overrides:**

```
.content-grid2 .grid-bottom-wrapper .grid-right {
  color: $color-red;
}
.content-grid2  .node--type-story.node--view-mode-teaser .content-wrap {
  color: $color-blue;
}
.content-grid2 .grid-top-wrapper {
  color: $color-orange;
}
```

Thank you in advance